# icons representing 'ABOUT' and 'CREDITS'

Tags: icons

I have three tabs of `ABOUT`, `CREDITS` and `LICENSE` like below:

[image]

I have selected an icon for `LICENSE`, but I'm not sure about `ABOUT` and `CREDITS`. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Eventually, I came up with the following icons for `ABOUT` and `CREDITS`:

[image]

Comment: We don't allow icon requests here. Icons are best if they clearly communicate their purpose. The fact that you cannot come up with icons yourself, it strongly suggests they may be challenging to communicate the purpose for those things. Sometime words work better than an icon for comprehension.

Comment: The litmus test with icons, is if you take them away does the link still make sense. In your case the links clearly still make sense because the links are textual. So unless you have a really good justification for using icons, I strongly suggest the icons are not providing any value here.

Comment: @SteveD Considering `Github.com` as an example, I feel like using an icon for every tab item might be justified. I'm not sure. Maybe visualizing items by icons has possible benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think these are concepts that have clear enough associations that can be encompassed by an icon. I mean, you can obviously make an icon that means about, but likely it'll be so ambiguous that users might think it means something else. Same with credits. I think it'd be better to use a label instead of an icon in this case.